# Ordenação com array multidimensional

Tags: php

Eu tenho o seguinte `array():`

```
$retorno[] = array(                 
"mes"=>$r1[3],
"ano"=>$r1[4],
"valor"=>$r1[2],
"codsubcategoria"=>$r1[6]
);
```

Que no `var_dump()` eu tenho a seguinte retorno, por exemplo:

```
[0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["mes"]=>
    string(1) "9"
    ["ano"]=>
    string(4) "2019"
    ["valor"]=>
    string(5) "30.75"
    ["codsubcategoria"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["mes"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["ano"]=>
    string(4) "2019"
    ["valor"]=>
    string(5) "30.75"
    ["codsubcategoria"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["mes"]=>
    string(2) "10"
    ["ano"]=>
    string(4) "2019"
    ["valor"]=>
    string(6) "325.00"
    ["codsubcategoria"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["mes"]=>
    string(1) "9"
    ["ano"]=>
    string(4) "2019"
    ["valor"]=>
    string(6) "325.00"
    ["codsubcategoria"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    ["mes"]=>
    string(1) "9"
    ["ano"]=>
    string(4) "2019"
    ["valor"]=>
    string(5) "23.00"
    ["codsubcategoria"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
```

Notem que na chave "mes" há meses de setembro e outubro misturado. Eu queria ordenar este retorno de acordo com ano e mês. Eu tentei com asort(), rsort(), mas não funcionou.

Se puderem me ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

LeoZera, por ser array multidimensional você precisa utilizar a função `array_multisort()` ela ordena múltiplos arrays ou arrays multidimensionais.

> A ordenação para ser utilizada no argumento array anterior. Pode ser SORT_ASC para ordenar na ascendente (crescente) SORT_DESC para ordernar na descendente (decrescente).

Abaixo você pode realizar da seguinte maneira para vc realizar o precisa:

```
<?php
$sortArray = array();
    foreach($retorno as $row){
        foreach($row as $key=>$value){ 
            if(!isset($sortArray[$key])){ 
                $sortArray[$key] = array(); 
            } 
                $sortArray[$key][] = $value;
        }
    } 

                array_multisort($sortArray['ano'],SORT_ASC,$sortArray['mes'],SORT_ASC, $retorno);
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: obrigado, funcionou era o que eu precisava. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue ordenar isso usando a função `usort`. Basta você criar uma função de comparação para passar como parâmetro para a função `usort`.

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['mes'] - $b['mes'];
}

// Passa o seu array e a função de comparação como callback
usort($retorno, 'sortByOrder');

print_r($retorno);
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [mes] => 9
            [ano] => 2019
            [valor] => 30.75
            [codsubcategoria] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [mes] => 9
            [ano] => 2019
            [valor] => 325.00
            [codsubcategoria] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [mes] => 9
            [ano] => 2019
            [valor] => 23.00
            [codsubcategoria] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [mes] => 10
            [ano] => 2019
            [valor] => 30.75
            [codsubcategoria] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [mes] => 10
            [ano] => 2019
            [valor] => 325.00
            [codsubcategoria] => 5
        )

)
```

Comment: Kayo, não funcionou ordenou o mes mas o ano ficou errado, eu precisava do mes e do ano ordenado

Comment: Teria como adaptar esta função para funcionar com mes e ano?

Comment: É verdade, deixei passar que precisava ordenar pelo ano também, mas da pra adaptar, assim que eu chegar em casa, eu faço esse ajuste e edito a resposta.